# sensor_msgs/Image encoding conversion

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to publish the ros image message encoded as "rgba8" from the original image, which has encoding "bgr8".

What would be a proper way to do that?

I'm thinking of doing it in the following steps:

1. convert ros image to cvImage
2. split the channels
3. merge the image according to "rgba" encoding (assuming a = 255)
4. convert new cvImage to ros image

This seems a bit tedious... any suggestions??

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65517/sensor_msgs/image-encoding-conversion/) by [Mikee](https://answers.ros.org/users/4974/mikee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-06-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look `cv_bridge`, the tutorial are plenty here http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages, select the appropriate ROS distro while at it.

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2013-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for pointing that out!

I tried to get the most out of that tutorial to do the conversion, and I just figured out the following:

1. convert the ros image (bgr8) to cvImage in cv_bridge by specifying the wanted encoding (rgba8).
2. convert this cvImage to ros msg, and publish.

When I run this script, it seems to consume quite a bit of cpu. I assume that during the first conversion, it needs lots of operations.

I just wonder if there would be a more efficient way of doing it?

---

Originally posted by [Mikee](https://answers.ros.org/users/4974/mikee/) with karma: 41 on 2013-06-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosqueries](https://answers.ros.org/users/6415/rosqueries/) on 2013-09-05**:
i also have to publish a cvMat image in ROS...can you please tell me how can i convert the cvMat to ROS msg image?

**Comment by [TimboInSpace](https://answers.ros.org/users/11216/timboinspace/) on 2014-11-17**:
Were you able to get any other conversions to work? I'm trying the same thing with RGB8 > Mono16, with no luck: `encoding specified as mono16, but image has incompatible type 8UC3`

Edit: My stream was only coming in as RGB8. This was the default in opencv, changing that fixed it.